# How do you execute a shell command in vba that uses stdio and stdout?

Tags: visual-studio, vba, dos

In visual studio I want a macro that takes the selected text, pipes it to a dos command, captures the resulting stream and replaces the selected text with it.

Something like this...

```
Dim objSel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
objSel.Text = RunShellCommand("beautify.rb", objSel.Text)
```

..where I don't know how to implement `RunShellCommand`.

It seems `Shell("beautify.rb", 1)` would execute a command and return the output, in which case all I need is .. "How do you stream text to the shell command?"

Comment: Have you looked at the "Windows Script Host Object Model"? You can find the MSDN reference for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a work around using AutoHotKey (an excellent tool) and changing `beautify.rb` to take a file.

```
;window ctrl R  - beautify sql
#^R::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   
clipboard = ; Start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived.
Send ^c
ClipWait  ; Wait for the clipboard to contain text.
FileDelete , c:\tmp\tmp_ahk_clip.txt
FileAppend , %clipboard% , c:\tmp\tmp_ahk_clip.txt
RunWait, %comspec% /c ""C:\...\Database\beautify.rb" c:\tmp\tmp_ahk_clip.txt > c:\tmp\tmp_ahk_clip_out.txt" ,,Hide
FileRead, clipboard, c:\tmp\tmp_ahk_clip_out.txt
Send ^v
Clipboard := ClipSaved 
ClipSaved = ; Free the memory 
return
```

Now any text field in any app with sql in it can be beautiful :)